# Magento custom CMS overflowing at the bottom of the homepage

Tags: magento

I am creating a custom CMS for the online store shop in magento. Just now i am facing this weird issue. The custom CMS which i have created is overflowing at the bottom, infact it is over lapping on top of the homepage footer. I have checked all the possible configuration but i am unable to find any. Has anyone faced such issue then please help me on this.

This is what is happening as shown below

[image]

Comment: You really need to give a lot more information. Like some code or an example. We know nothing about your custom CMS.

Comment: When the custom CMS content is short then its OK. But when the contents are growing lengthy then it is overlapping the homepage footer.

Answer (score 0):

You should mess around with `display:block`'s and `overflow:hidden`'s in your stylesheet.